# How display a image in java from a file text that contain integers with grayscale?

Tags: java, arrays, awt, bufferedimage, grayscale

I have a university problem that consists of a black and white photograph represented as a matrix of size `mxn` where each position `(i, j)` is a value `0-255` that indicates the gray tone of the corresponding pixel, I am trying to show the image but a blue background comes out, I appreciate if anyone knows the solution to the problem.

What I am doing is the following:

First step: load the txt file into an array

Second step :

```
 BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage (width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    image.setRGB (0, 0, width, height, data, 0, width);
    g.drawImage (image, 0, 0, this);
```

but it only shows me a blue image with noise.

Comment: Well, how do you load `data` and what does it contain? Probably you will have to spread the read data into an R, G and B bytes with the same value.

Comment: What is the exact type of `data`?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the text file.

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating the image as RGB (color) but you said it's a grayscale -- try this:

**`BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY`**

```
BufferedImage image = 
    new BufferedImage (640, 480, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
```